# CS50 Tideman - Print winner works for me, but i kinda smells

Tags: c, cs50

Everything works fine in my program, you probably shouldn't read the spoilers if you are still trying to figure out how to make it work.

I found a way to find the winner of an election, I go through the column of every candidate in the locked 2d array, if one of the value is true, then I change candidate, because this one is not the source of the graph (one arrow is pointing to him)

This is how I wrote it in code :

```
void print_winner(void)
{
    int i = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
    {
        if (locked[j][i] == true)
        {
            i++;
            j = -1;
        }
    }

    printf("%s\n", candidates[i]);
    return;
}
```

I've got an issue with assigning the -1 value to j (because when the loop starts again with a new i, j increments automatically, so I had to do that in order to check for j = 0)

Is there a way to make this less "smelly" ?

I tried with j = 0; but the next iteration of the loop increments j to 1, skipping the checking for j = 0

Answer (score 1):

Just use `while` loop instead of `for` and increment `j` only when you need to.

```c
void print_winner(void)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (j < candidate_count)
    {
        if (locked[j][i] == true)
        {
            i++;
            j = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            j++;
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", candidates[i]);
    return;
}
```

Comment: The comparison to `true` seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You want to try each `i` in succession until you find one that works.  That sounds like a loop to me.  How about something like this, then:

```
void print_winner(void) {
    int i = 0;

    for (; i < candidate_count; i++) {
        int j = 0;

        for (; j < candidate_count && !locked[j][i]; j++) { /* empty */ }
        if (j == candidate_count) {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (i < candidate_count) {
        printf("%s\n", candidates[i]);
    } else {
        printf("error\n");
    }
}
```

The outer loop runs over `i`, aborting if you exhaust all the candidates without finding a suitable one (presumably that constitutes a data error).  With `i` being declared outside the loop, it will retain its value when the loop terminates.

The inner loop runs over `j`.  Again, `j` is declared so as to remain accessible and retain its value when the loop terminates.  At that point, we know by the final value of `j` whether any of the elements of `locked` that were tested evaluated to true.  If none did, then we `break` from the outer loop.  Otherwise, execution cycles back to the top of the outer loop.